# Flutter : 'onError' is deprecated on runZoned function

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error message when I using newest Flutter v 1.17.1 and Dart 2.8.2 version on main.dart file,

> 'onError' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use runZonedGuarded instead.
>   Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

and this is the code,

```
  runZoned<Future<Null>>(() async {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, onError: (error, stackTrace) async {
    await FlutterCrashlytics().reportCrash(error, stackTrace, forceCrash: false);
  });
}
```

Any solution to get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
runZonedGuarded(() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}, (Object error, StackTrace stack) async {
  await FlutterCrashlytics().reportCrash(error, stackTrace, forceCrash: false);
});
```