# flutter zone vs future

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I read about Zone and have used Futures in many languages. I know about Event Loop and that Dart is single threaded. However, when I write following code I could not differentiate how differently it will work and when to use one over another.

What is the difference between zone and future?

For example here:

```dart
runZoned(() async {
  // Do Something
}, onError: (e, stackTrace) {
  print(e);
});
```

Vs

```dart
someAsyncCall().catchError((e) {

  print(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[Futures error handling](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling)

[Zones](https://dart.dev/articles/archive/zones)

[What is a Future](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#what-is-a-future)

Edit 1: I used *runZonedGuarded* instaed *runZoned* because *runZoned.onError* is deprecated.

[Flutter : 'onError' is deprecated on runZoned function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078458/flutter-onerror-is-deprecated-on-runzoned-function)

Hi! With runZoned you can basically Handling asynchronous errors that are commonly caused by futures (http request, etc). The concept is similar to a try-catch in synchronous code. With Future you cannot do that.

runZoned example:

```
runZonedGuarded(() {
  _timerError();
}, (error, stack) {
  print('Uncaught error runZoneGuard: $error');
});
```

resullt:

```
I/flutter (13567): Uncaught error runZoneGuard: asynchronous error
```

Future example:

```
someCall().then((value) {
  _timerError();
}, onError: (value) {
  print('Uncaught error onError: $value');
}).catchError((e) {
  print('Uncaught error catchError: $e');
});
```

result:

```
E/flutter (13567): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: asynchronous error
E/flutter (13567): #0      _MyHomePageState._timerError.<anonymous closure> (package:async_study/main.dart:60:7)
E/flutter (13567): #1      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
E/flutter (13567): #2      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (13567): #3      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (13567): #4      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (13567): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
E/flutter (13567): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (13567): #7      _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1260:23)
E/flutter (13567): #8      Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (13567): #9      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (13567): #10     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (13567): #11     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

And the '_timerError()' method used to trhow an async error:

```
void _timerError() {
    Timer.run(() {
      throw "asynchronous error";
    });
}
```

Comment: runZonedGuarded doesn't catch my socket exception from a post request when server is down...

I tried several tricks...


My code
  `runZonedGuarded(() async {
      res = await post(loginSellerUrl, body);
    }, (error, stack) {
      print('Uncaught error runZoneGuard: $error');
      res = null;
      throw Exception('ERROR unhandled');
    });`